# Pandas series str.extract fails to match RegEx Pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Following is what My Dataframe Looks like 
mydf =

```
col1    Col2    Col3                 Col4 
0   val1    1x  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t3x\n\t\t\t\t\t    Calculate
1   val2    1x  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t3x\n\t\t\t\t\t    Calculate
2   val3    1x  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t12.5x\n\t\t\t\t\t Calculated
3   val4    1x  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t8x\n\t\t\t\t\t        Calculated
4   val5    1x  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t10x\n\t\t\t\t\t   Calculate
5   val18   1x  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t6.3x\n\t\t\t\t\t  Calculate
```

from the Col4 , I would like to extract the Number (including the decimal places.

However, the regex pattern isn't working for me.

```
mydf[Col4].str.extract('[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?') <br>
```

For most of the Rows it returns `NaN` for the ones with decimals this returns `.5` / `.3` (i.e. Just the decimal Value)

I have tried using re.search to check my pattern and it works.

```
newstr = mydf[col4][5] 
re.search('[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?', newstr)
```

newstr becomes - '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t12.5x\n\t\t\t\t\t'
(DOUBLE Backslash).
The above returns

```
re.Match object; span=(14, 18), match='12.5'</b>
```

as expected.

Looks like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: These breaks (`<br>`) in your dataframe? Can we remove them?

Comment: removed them from the df

Comment: Your regex works completely fine with `extract`. It extracts [exclusively the capture group](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) `(\.\d+)?`. You should modify this regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `str.findall`

```
df.Col3.str.findall(r'[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+').str[0]#notice here I also extract the sign
0       3
1       3
2    12.5
3       8
4      10
5     6.3
Name: Col3, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can also `strip` and avoid regexes

```
df.Col3.str.strip().str[:-1]

0       3
1       3
2    12.5
3       8
4      10
5     6.3
Name: Col3, dtype: object
```

Comment: afraid this did not work, the column does not change (strip) with this. Maybe the Col3 is Padded (with Spaces or sth).

Comment: @Suraj_j `strip` should also take care of whitespaces etc